# Proper way to use :not selector along with "attribute contains" selector

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors

I am creating a bootstrap layout and have a need to collapse the padding/margin on all col-* columns except col-xs-* columns. I tried the below selector to no avail.

```
.grid [class^="col-"]:not([class^="col-xs-"]) {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Maybe I am confusing something or this just isn't supported? I understand that I can use the following, but was wondering why the above solution doesn't work.

```
.grid [class^="col-sm-"], .grid [class^="col-md-"], .grid [class^="col-lg-"] {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the two snippets side by side?

Comment: Can you show us the affected portion(s) of your HTML?

Comment: Because xs is outside the media queries and the same class xs in on the sm or md or lg. See http://jsbin.com/fabos/2/edit

Comment: @BootstrapThemer: That does not change the fact that an element that matches `[class^="col-xs-"]` could not possibly simultaneously match any of `[class^="col-sm-"], [class^="col-md-"], [class^="col-lg-"]`, since it would have to have multiple `class` attributes and not just multiple class names for that to happen, which isn't possible. If anything, it can be presumed that the reason the OP is using `^=` attribute selectors is precisely this.

Comment: The class col-xs-* is used on the col-sm-*, col-md-* element, so the the element is matching both. It works fine if you just have col-sm-* and not col-xs-* on the same element

Comment: @BootstrapThemer is right on. If you would make your comment(s) an answer I will accept it. I needed to use media queries *facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class col-xs-* is used on the col-sm-, col-md- element, so the the element is matching both. It works fine if you just have col-sm-* and not col-xs-* on the same element.

```
@media (min-width:768px) {

  .row.grid {margin-left:0;margin-right:0;}
  .grid [class*="col-"] {padding:0;}

}
```

**http://jsbin.com/fabos/2/edit**